# Tiny spark when connecting VGA monitors to PC

Tags: display, power-supply, vga

I think I'm having a problem with either my PC, or my monitor(s), or my home electrical system, and I'd need some help to determine what is actually happening.

It all started when I was doing some maintenance to my headless PC (I use as a server). I disconnected the power plug, drained the PSU by pressing the power button, and started opening the case. As I touched the metal case inside, I felt some mild electric shocks on my hands. I tried disconnecting all cables connected to the case one by one, and I came to the conclusion that I felt the shocks only when the VGA cable was connected.

I did some tests, and it looks like when I touch the case with the VGA connector (from the monitor) it makes some tiny sparks, indicating there is a current leak somewhere. At first, I thought the monitor was defective. However, the same exact thing happens with a second monitor (actually, it is a TV).

Everything works fine, but this thing scares me a little bit, because I'm afraid it could worsen and become dangerous.

What should I do? Is this normal for some reason?

Comment: Sounds like static to me.

Comment: It doesn't help to unplug the PC if it is connected to devices that are plugged in.  Isolate the PC.